# Selenium doesn't seem to load the JavaScript part of the website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

hello i have a script using Python and Selenium, and I don't understand why this can't retrieve the JS part of the website (the same script works perfectly fine on my other machine):

```
        import chromedriver_binary
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1024,768")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
        
        url = "https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/london/holborn?geohash=gcpvj6kxet58&collection=pizza"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

        show_data = soup.find_all("script", id="__NEXT_DATA__")
        mydata = json.loads( show_data[0].text )
```

I get the following error, meaning that it couldn't see this part of JSON:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Not too sure why this is working on my other machine and not on my current one.

Comment: Had you even lookup the variable show_data??

Comment: it's empty as there is nothing in the "script" section. Whereas there should be.

Comment: if its empty you should get index error on show_data[0] no?

Comment: show_data[0].text returns an empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.text` attribute doesn't work here. To get the right data, it worked for me to use `encode_contents()`, just changing the definition of `mydata` like this:

```
mydata = json.loads( show_data[0].encode_contents())
```